# Does Selenium wait for JavaScript to complete?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I am testing a JavaScript API using Java/Selenium.

I issue these commands on Java side,

```
executor.executeScript("setName('Hello');");
// Thread.sleep(2000);
String output = (String)executor.executeScript("return getName()");
assertEquals(output, "Hello");
```

In JavaScript side, this is an async function, so it is supposed to take some time and set the variable.

```
function setName(msg) {
    // simulate async call 
    setName(function(){name = msg;},1000);
}
```

I need to wait for this async function to complete before moving to the next line in Java, where the `assertEquals()` is executed.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using `Thread.sleep()` on Java side.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily ask Selenium to wait until a particular condition is true; in exactly what you have, one alternative would be:

```
new FluentWait<JavascriptExecutor>(executor) {
  protected RuntimeException timeoutException(
      String message, Throwable lastException) {
    Assert.fail("name was never set");
  }
}.withTimeout(10, SECONDS)
.until(new Predicate<JavascriptExecutor>() {
  public boolean apply(JavascriptExecutor e) {
    return (Boolean)executor.executeScript("return ('Hello' === getName());");
  }
});
```

However, then you're basically testing exactly what you just coded, and that has the disadvantage that if `name` were set before you called `setName`, you haven't necessarily waited `setName` to finish. One thing I've done in the past for similar things is this:

In my testing library (which replaces real async calls with `setTimeout` shims), I have this:

```
window._junit_testid_ = '*none*';
window._junit_async_calls_ = {};
function _setJunitTestid_(testId) {
  window._junit_testid_ = testId;
}
function _setTimeout_(cont, timeout) {
  var callId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
  var testId = window._junit_testid_;
  window._junit_async_calls_[testId] |= {};
  window._junit_async_calls_[testId][callId] = 1;
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    cont();
    delete(window._junit_async_calls_[testId][callId]);
  }, timeout);
}
function _isTestDone_(testId) {
  if (window._junit_async_calls_[testId]) {
    var thing = window._junit_async_calls_[testId];
    for (var prop in thing) {
      if (thing.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
    }
    delete(window._junit_async_calls_[testId]);
  }
  return true;
}
```

In the rest of my library, I use `_setTimeout_` instead of `window.setTimeout` whenever I need to set something up to happen later. Then, in my selenium test, I do something like this:

```
// First, this routine is in a library somewhere
public void waitForTest(JavascriptExecutor executor, String testId) {
  new FluentWait<JavascriptExecutor>(executor) {
    protected RuntimeException timeoutException(
        String message, Throwable lastException) {
      Assert.fail(testId + " did not finish async calls");
    }
  }.withTimeout(10, SECONDS)
  .until(new Predicate<JavascriptExecutor>() {
    public boolean apply(JavascriptExecutor e) {
      return (Boolean)executor.executeScript(
          "_isTestDone_('" + testId + "');");
    }
  });
}

// Inside an actual test:
@Test public void serverPingTest() {
  // Do stuff to grab my WebDriver instance
  // Do this before any interaction with the app
  driver.executeScript("_setJunitTestid_('MainAppTest.serverPingTest');");
  // Do other stuff including things that fire off what would be async calls
  // but now call stuff in my testing library instead.
  // ...
  // Now I need to wait for all the async stuff to finish:
  waitForTest(driver, "MainAppTest.serverPingTest");
  // Now query stuff about the app, assert things if needed
}
```

Note that you can call `waitForTest` multiple times if needed, any time you need that test to pause until all async operations are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt selenium does. It only waits for page to be completely loaded, but not a script to finish. You may wish to define your own 'test step' for waiting for result (and constantly polling the page contents/script state), but be sure to setup reasonable timout not to male your tests hang forever on script error.